# Should you compare a float with 0.0

Tags: floating-point, compare

Remember how floats can't be compared with == against constant, because the float representation may not exists for the constant. Is that also true for 0.0? Or do most (or all) floating point engines have a special representation for 0.0

I'm looking for languages, IEEE specifications or floating point engines where this works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero is guaranteed to be representable on any IEEE-754 system, and I know of no other floating-point system in which zero is not exactly representable.  That's not to say that such a system couldn't exist, but it would be *highly* unusual.

Answer (score 2):

A better idea is to compare the absolute value of the difference between two floating point values to a small (epsilon) value rather than zero:

```
private static final double EPSILON = 1.0e-6;

if (Math.abs(x-y) < EPSILON) {
   // process here
}
```

Values of x or y equal to zero are special cases.

Comment: Thank you, its a better idea yes. We were just discussing here though if 0.0 has a special treatment or not. Have updated question.